# html compatible Timer that doesn't pause on defocus?

Tags: timer, libgdx

I have a libgdx project which I wish to deploy to both desktop and web.

I used  `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer` in the project, but found it paused if the app was defocused. So instead I switched to just  `java.util.Timer` which keeps ticking regardless.
However, this gives compile errors under gwt.

So I am looking for pointers on a Timer solution that works on both, yet also lets the app count "in the background".

Ideas;

- do I extend/modify  `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer` somehow?
- or use `java.util.Timer` in core, but somehow tell gwt compiles to use a different class?
- alternatives?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your two options :

1. I suggest you to use `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer` but it paused if your app will defocused because your task is scheduled on `TimerThread` that is managed by LibGDX framework itself by `pause()` and `resume()` lifecycle method. You need to override pause method of `ApplicationListener` and start timer by yourself.

   ```
   @Override
   public void pause() {
      Timer.instance().start();
   }
   ```
2. `java.util.Timer` throw gwt compiler error, may be not supported on GWT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your correct, javas Timer is not supported on gwt. I was hesistant to use solution 1 though as it seemed silly to let the timer stop only to restart it. Fortunately I found another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the gwt.xml configuration file.
Using the "super-source" tag you can specify a sub-package whos contents will be used in place of java files elsewhere.
You have to make sure the subpackages complete path matchs, then it works perfect.

ie, this is in my gwt.xml at com.lostagain.jamgdx

```
<!--    This overrides the default timer class in JamGdx-core with a gwt specific implementation -->
<!-- This is because the core method uses javas Timer out of preferance for its behavour, which gwt does not support. -->
<!-- The gwt class uses its own timer method instead. -->   

    <super-source path="gwtonly"/>
```

and I placed my gwt specific timer replacement at;

```
com.lostagain.jamgdx.gwtonly.com.lostagain.jamgdx.implementations
```

in the gwt project.
(as my normal timer was at `com.lostagain.jamgdx.implementations` in Core)